# Swift: Override Subclass Properties that are also Subclasses of the Parent Class Property Class

Tags: swift, overriding, subclass

Seems like a confusing question to word but it's actually pretty simple. I want to do something like this but Swift won't allow it:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
class C {
    var prop: A?
}
class D : C {
    override var prop : B?
}
```

Comment: D is not subclass of anything. Could you re-clarify your question ?

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa oops mistype please check now

Comment: @ThomMorgan what does the compiler complain about exactly?

Comment: @LoicVerrall the compiler shows `Cannot override mutable property 'prop' of type 'A?' with covariant type 'B?'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html):

> Overriding Property Getters and Setters
>
> You can provide a custom getter (and setter, if appropriate) to
>   override any inherited property, regardless of whether the inherited
>   property is implemented as a stored or computed property at source.
>   The stored or computed nature of an inherited property is not known by
>   a subclass—it only knows that the inherited property has a certain
>   name and type. **You must always state both the name and the type of the
>   property you are overriding, to enable the compiler to check that your
>   override matches a superclass property with the same name and type.**

Seems like you cant do that.

Comment: dang that kinda sucks

Comment: Looks like it's now supported in Swift 4.2  at least for non-stored properties

Answer (score 0):

There's no sensible way to do what you're asking, which is covariance/contravariance. Imagine this code:

```
func storeProperty(_ c: C) {
  c.prop = A()
}

let d = D()
storeProperty(d)
let b: B = d.prop
```

If your idea were to work, we have a type error — a variable of type B that doesn't contain a B at runtime!